# Make Video Streaming URL secure from Logging in Logcat

Tags: android, video-streaming, android-videoview

Currently I'm trying to simply stream a Video from some link this way:

```
try {
    videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);

    MediaController vidControl = new MediaController(this);
    vidControl.setAnchorView(videoView);
    videoView.setMediaController(vidControl);
    videoView.setVideoPath("http://some.link/some_video.mp4");
    loadingProgress.show();

    videoView.requestFocus();
    videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            loadingProgress.dismiss();
            videoView.start();
        }
    });
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Everything is going OK, but I want to make that URL (i.e. http://some.link/some_video.mp4) secure. I mean user won't be able to download this video.

> The problem is: before loading this video, the **logcat** is
>   displaying log like this:

```
my.app.package.name W/MediaPlayer: Couldn't open http://some.link/some_video.mp4: java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: http://some.link/some_video.mp4
```

> I have noticed:
>
> 1. Even the code is not going into **CATCH** block.
> 2. Made **SIGNED App**, but that **LOG** is still appearing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those logs are built into the framework MediaPlayer class.  The only way I know of to remove it is to take the MediaPlayer code from AOSP, copy it to a class in your app, remove all the log statements, and use that instead of the Android MediaPlayer class.